# php echo contains \n\n

Tags: php, codeigniter

for some reason my php echo contains two extra `\n` at the start of string.
I couldn't see a reason why, I have infact all the php files ending without `?>` so there is no point that it could have come due to a `\n` after the `?>` characters

Comment: What about newlines *before* `<?php` ?

Comment: nope there are no newlines before <?php   I have written many pieces of api before, this is the first time I saw this weird issue

Comment: By now i have never experienced such issues appearing due to some error in apache/php parser. i am 99.9% sure that there is some typo/logical mistake. Post your code we will inspect it :)